# How do I express a list or array of objects in yaml via a Spring placeholder?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, yaml, placeholder

I know that you can override yaml config values with placeholders like so:

```
some-setting: ${SOME_SETTING:default value}
```

And I know that you can express lists of objects like so:

```
customers:
  - name: acme
    category: manufacturing
    employees: 200 
  - name: virtucon
    category: evil
    employees: 1
```

So how would I express such a list via the ${} placeholder notation?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to create a ConfigurationProperties to read in the property objects.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class AppProperties {

    private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

    public static class Customer {
        private String name;
        private String category;
        private int employees;
    }
}
```

Usually you would also create a prefix for this in your .yml file also

```
app:
   customers:
   - name: acme
     category: manufacturing
     employees: 200
   - name: virtucon
     category: evil
     employees: 1
```

You can now auto-wire this class anywhere in your application.

Comment: Not _quite_ the same thing.  I know how to read properties from YAML, the idea here is to use the Spring ${} placeholder notation in the static YAML such that the values can be injected elsewhere.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to use the value placeholder to read complex objects. You can get individual fields like this @Value("${customers[0].name}")


https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties